# HTML on mouseover a[tag], changing img src attribute with css3 smooth transition

Tags: jquery, animation, transition, mouseover, mouseout

This is my Code,

**HTML**

```
<ul id="submenu">
<li data-img="submenu1.jpg"><a href="#">Experience</a></li>
<li>....</li>
<li>....</li>
</ul>

<img id="company-image" data-original="company.jpg" src="company.jpg">
```

**jQuery**

```
$("#submenu li").hover(function() {
            $("#company-image").attr("src", $(this).data("img"));
        }, function(){
            $("#company-image").attr("src", $("#company-image").data("original"));
        });
```

here when i mouseover on the li, removing the existing img src value and adding new img name(submenu1.jpg), while this i need to show the transition for old to new img changing time. and onmouseout time need to show fadeout effect.

Answer (score 0):

Try the .fadeOut() function of them image.

```
$("#company-image").attr("src", $(this).data("img")).fadeOut(500);
```

here is the w3schools link
http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/eff_fadeout.asp

you'll also have to set a setTimeout() on the new image loading

```
$("#submenu li").hover(function() {
        $("#company-image").attr("src", $(this).data("img").FadeOut(500));
    }, setTimeout(function(){
        $("#company-image").attr("src", $("#company-image").data("original"));
    }), 550);
```